# R Date format changed after sapply

Tags: r, date, sapply

```
age <- c(22,24,NA,27)
duedate <- as.Date(c("1/1/2020",NA,"1/30/2020","12/31/2021"), format="%m/%d/%Y")
df <- data.frame(age,duedate)

Minimum <- sapply(df, function(x) min(x,na.rm=T))
Maximum <- sapply(df, function(x) max(x,na.rm=T))
tbl <- data.frame(min_scale,max_Scale)
print(tbl)
tbl[2,1] <- as.Date(tbl[2,1],origin = "1970-01-01") #Do not work
```

[image]
[image]

After making the table, the dates were changed to numeric values and I can't return it back.
Any suggestion? I want to show the dates like the right table.
I want to do it automatically as much as possible as I have lots of variables.

Comment: Use `lapply` rather than `sapply`. You can't have mixed types in a vector. Since Age can't be converted to a date, both Age and Duedate are converted to numeric values.  if you use `lapply` to get a list, you can have mixed types. But even then you can't have mixed types in the column of a data.frame. If this is just to make things look pretty, you'll need to convert everything to a string/character value to preserve formatting.

Comment: Dates in R are of type numeric, so when attributes get dropped in the process of simplifying to array, the dates reveal their underlying values. The current code makes no sense because the names min_scale and max_scale are obviously supposed to be Minimum and Maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit simpler and results in a data frame in the same orientation as `df` with the `age` and `duedate` in separate columns:

```
tbl <- as.data.frame(rbind(Minimum, Maximum))
tbl$duedate <- as.Date(tbl$duedate, "1970-01-01")
tbl
#         age    duedate
# Minimum  22 2020-01-01
# Maximum  27 2021-12-31
```

Comment: I transposed the table and got I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. This will work for multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = list(Min = min, Max = max), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% # Apply min and max function
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%                                # Convert all columns to character
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Parameter") %>%                 # Convert to long format
  separate(Parameter, into = c("Parameter", "Statistics")) %>%           # Separate the Parameter columns
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Statistics", values_from = "value")          # Convert to wide format

df2
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Parameter Min        Max       
#   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 age       22         27        
# 2 duedate   2020-01-01 2021-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the base function summary and leave out the statsitics that don't interest you:

```
summary(df)[c(1,6), ]  # for numeric values min and max are the 1st and 6th rows.
#-------------------------
      age           duedate          
 Min.   :22.00   Min.   :2020-01-01  
 Max.   :27.00   Max.   :2021-12-31
```